# Login with specific user on Laravel 4

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have different users, some of them are plain users, and a few are admins.
What I need is that the admins can login as any of the other users by just clicking a button in the user list.

What I have so far is:

index.blade.php (the users list):

```
<a href='{{URL::route('users.loginas', array('id' => $user->id))}}'>LoginAs</a>
```

routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as'=>'index', 'uses'=>'HomeController@showWelcome'));

    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::any('users/loginas/{id}', array('as'=>'users.loginas', 'uses' => 'UsersController@loginAs'));

});
```

UsersController.php:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

...

public function loginAs($id)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Auth::loginUsingId($id);

        return Redirect::route('provalogin');
    }

}
```

When I click the link for the user with ID 2 from the users list while logged in with the user with ID 1, I am correctly redirected to mysite.com/users/loginas/2 but then it throws an ErrorException:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement
>   interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given, called in
>   /var/www/mysite.com/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php
>   on line 368 and defined

Then, if I change the URL to mysite.com/users I can see that I'm in fact logged in as the new user, so the `Auth::loginUsingId(2)` worked.

What am I doing wrong? or how should I do it?

Comment: Can you try it without ```Auth::logout()```? It seems both ```Auth::logout()``` and ```Auth::loginUsingId()``` can't be called in the same request.

Comment: Without the `Auth::logout()` it does not crash, but also it does not switch the logged useras I keep seing everithing as if I still was the admin user. :(

Comment: I have run into the same issue. I noticed that if you use Auth::login instead of Auth::loginUsingId I actually relogin with new user. But what's the difference between these methods and how to go back to admin - I dont have any clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is use Session to set userID equal to the auth user id. Then if I want to switch users I just change the session userID but keep the auth user id as myself. In my application I always pass the session userID when querying for data. If I update, create or soft delete a record I pass my auth user id. That way I have a record of who actually changed the data. I never have to log out to switch users, just set the Session userID.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you user model is not setup correctly, inheriting UserInterface.

Your User model should look something like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface
```

And your auth.php config should look something like this:

```
return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Authentication Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
    | This drivers manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
    | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Model
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
    | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
    |
    */

    'model' => 'User',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
    | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
    | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
    |
    */

    'table' => '',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reminder Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
    | that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
    | be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
    |
    */

    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.forgot-pass', 'table' => 'forgot_pass'
    ),

)
```

Comment: But that's not all, he also has to implement getAuthIdentifier() and getAuthPassword() in order for UserInterface to work.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418085/laravel-4-auth-with-facebook-no-password-authentication

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with `\Session::flush();` . It seemed that some variables were still remembered in the session.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my user was empty and I solved by loading a correct user, I don't know if it will work for you too but you can try.