# Laravel 4 Auth with Facebook (no password authentication)

Tags: facebook, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up an authentication system with Laravel 4 with a Facebook login.  I am using the madewithlove/laravel-oauth2 package for Laravel 4.

Of course, there is no password to add to my database upon a user loggin in with Facebook.  I am, however, trying to check to see if a user id is in the database already to determine if I should create a new entity, or just log in the current one.  I would like to use the Auth commands to do this.  I have a table called "fans".

This is what I'm working with:

```
 $fan = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid']);

                if(is_null($fan)) {

                  $fan = new Fan;

                  $fan->fbid = $user['uid'];
                  $fan->email = $user['email'];
                  $fan->first_name = $user['first_name'];
                  $fan->last_name = $user['last_name'];
                  $fan->gender = $user['gender'];
                  $fan->birthday = $user['birthday'];
                $fan->age = $age;
                $fan->city = $city;
                $fan->state = $state;
                  $fan->image = $user['image'];

                  $fan->save();

                  return Redirect::to('fans/home');

                }

                else {

                  Auth::login($fan);
                  return Redirect::to('fans/home');

               }
```

Fan Model:

```
<?php

class Fan extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();
}
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given
```

EDIT:  When I use: `$fan = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid'])->first();`

I get the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php on line 368 and defined
```

I do not know why it is giving me this error.  Do you have suggestions on how I can make this work?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you show your code for Fan class??

Comment: Fan model code added.

Comment: Error explains it all...you are extending your fan model to use Eloquent, where as for Auth to work you should also implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface

Comment: how do I do this?  I tried writing "implements UserInterace" at the top of the model and it gave me an error.

Comment: did you reference the UserInterface like use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

Comment: yes, I still receive the same error.

Comment: does anyone have an idea on this issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506327/laravel-facebook-login-missing-email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement UserInterface to your model for Auth to work properly

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
class Fan extends Eloquent implements UserInterface{
...
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
}
```

getAuthIdentifier and getAuthPassword are abstract method and must be implemented in you class implementing UserInterface

Comment: do you also have any idea on this issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506327/laravel-facebook-login-missing-email

Answer (score 0):

To login any user into the system, you need to use the `User` model, and I bet inherited classes will do the trick as well but I'm not sure.

Anyway, your `Fan` model does not associate with the `User` model/table in any way and that's a problem. If your model had a `belong_to` or `has_one` relationship and a `user_id` field then you could replace `Auth::login($user)` with `Auth::loginUsingId(<some id>)`.

---

Original answer:

You are missing an extra method call: `->get()` or `->first()` to actually retrieve the results:

```
$fan = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid'])->first();
```

Alternatively, you can throw an exception to see what's going on:

```
$fan = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid'])->firstOrFail();
```

If you see different errors, update your question with those errors.

Comment: I tried it like this and it just gave me a different, but similar error.

Comment: Weird, you check for null values, but still you got an error about a null value

Comment: any other ideas?  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I changed the default authentication model in auth.php from User to Fan.  I also changed the authentication table to fans as opposed to the default users, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: How many `Fan` rows does the table have? Do you see any errors if you try this?: `$fan = Fan::create(array( 'email' => 'test@so.com' )); $fan-save(); Auth::loginUsingId($fan->id);`

Comment: @AstDerek do you also have any idea on this issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506327/laravel-facebook-login-missing-email