# Laravel basic-auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to use `basic.auth` for my web page but authentication donst work

## routes.php

### `admin` - authentication

```
Route::get('admin', array('before' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
    return 'Top secret';
}));
```

### `create` - create test user

```
Route::get('create', function()
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->email = 'test@test.com';
    $user->username = 'test';
    $user->password = Hash::make('password');
    $user->save();
});
```

## config

- `app/config/app` - has defined `key` (that created Laravel installation)
- `app/config/auth` - has defined `model` (`User`) and `table` (`users`)

## filters.php

### `auth.basic`

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});
```

## test

I call `/create` to create User `test@test.com`:`password`

Here is `users` table after:
[image]

Then I call `/admin` to login

[image]

But it doesnt let me in. After <kbd>Login</kbd> - it just clear inputs. After <kbd>Cancel</kbd> - it return `Invalid credentials.`.

---

## User model

I tried implement `UserInterface`

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->passsword;
    }
}
```

---

## Problem solved

I had typo in `User` model `return $this->passsword;` There is 3 `s`.

Now I use default Laravel [User model](http://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php).

Comment: 1) do you have any attribute modifiers is the User model? - especially for password (I had a setter that automaticly hashed the given value, so I double hashed my password) and 2) did you try another browser?

Comment: @RobGordijn - 1) User model has only - `class User extends Eloquent {}`. 2) google chrome, firefox

Comment: Does your user model implements UserInterface???

Comment: @RobGordijn - no, I didnt find anthing about that in docs

Comment: if you don't implement userinterface in your user model it will not work

Comment: ok and what shoud return `getAuthIdentifier` and `getAuthPassword`?

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418085/laravel-4-auth-with-facebook-no-password-authentication/17419236#17419236) is your solution

Comment: I tried this and its still not work, ... anyway, I have set `User` model and `users` table in `auth.php`

Comment: can you show your user model code

Comment: Take a look at the default `User.php` model that Laravel 4 ships with.

Comment: @JasonLewis - default `User.php` model has `class User extends Eloquent {}` ... its doesnt work, I also tried implement `UserInterface`, still nothing changed :/

Comment: Where are you looking exactly? This is the default model that Laravel 4 ships with: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/models/User.php

Comment: @JasonLewis - oh, I will try, after installation I has clear User model, thx

Comment: @JasonLewis - yes! thats solve my problem, i had typo in `return $this->passsword;` 3x s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that in app/config/auth.php - `driver` is set to `eloquent`.

You may also need to implement the `UserInterface` interface (`class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface`) - then you'll need to include the methods in your model:

```
/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
```

Comment: Yes its set to eloquent | `auth.php` - `'driver' => 'eloquent'`

Comment: Your answer is quite good ... I had typo in `return $this->passsword;` - 3x `s`

Comment: Oh nice, PEBKAC error. Yea, those are hard for us to diagnose :)