# auth.basic keeps on asking for username/password - laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, basic-authentication

I read this thread
[Laravel basic-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447617/laravel-basic-auth)
but he found out there's a type because of User model but I checked mine and I'm using the default User model from laravel and getting the same problem.
I actually tried locally and it worked perfectly but after I uploaded to the server it just kept on asking me for username/password.

I have this in my routes

```
Route::get('/', function()
{   
    $user = User::create(array(
            'username' => 'test@test.test',
            'password' => Hash::make('test')
        ));
    $user->save();
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.basic'), function(){
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
});
```

I tried this way to go into public to create the fields in my database.  After created I went to /public/posts and it asked kept on telling me to sign in.  Again I tried this way locally and worked perfectly.

anyone has any idea?

Comment: Check your config? Do you have cookies, etc. set up properly?

Comment: I emptied my cookies and I tried with my laptop and having the same problem too...:(

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/security#http-basic-authentication) states that by default the basic authentication will use the `email` column on the user record when authenticating, but you have a `username` column instead.

Basically, you need to tell the filter, that you want to use that column in filters.php:

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
});
```

Comment: oh ya I done this already....if I didn't put 'username' it'll give me an error when I try to load the page

Comment: Which PHP implementation is your PHP where this doesn't work?

Comment: I go into let's say http://mydomain.com/testing/public/posts then it'll ask for the authentication right? I enter the authentications I created and it just empty the fields and asks me to enter username / password again.  I tried the same thing locally like http://localhost/testing/public/posts and authentication does pop up too but after I enter the username / password the page loads perfectly.  If I enter incorrect the fields empties for me to retry.  That's why I said locally it worked fine but after I uploaded it to a server it just kept on asking me to retry

Comment: That didn't answer my question?

Comment: No, I was wondering whether you are using PHP as an Apache module or with CGI implementation on the server where it doesn't work?

Comment: I believe it's PHP.  I'm still new with this :(